# Word for a person you consider personal and don't want to share with anyone

Tags: single-word-requests

What term is used for a person whom you consider *yours* and don't want to share him with anyone?

Comment: ?? Dominatrix ??

Comment: In most Englsih speaking countries, we have rules against owning people.

Comment: my precious?...

Comment: It would help to know the context of your attempted description. Right now, we can only guess why it’s insufficiently descriptive to call this person your _boyfriend_ or say, simply, “he’s mine.” As others have noted, nothing you’ve said makes it clear what it is about this other person that you’re reluctant to share (assuming you aren’t asking about literally, wholly owning another person). Do you not want others to be able to talk to him? Do you not want others to know about him?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then why not edit? .....I suggested an edit before I saw your comment.

Comment: This whole Q&A thread got really weird, awful fast.

Comment: *Get your lying filthy grubby little hands off my man, you thieving bitch* I'd say conveys the message  who's the "boss".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Since a good chunk of these comments got deleted, I'm sure I'm (literally) missing something, but why do you say OP isn't coming back? It's been less than a day since their post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Makes sense.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds as though you are describing a "*thrall*" or "*slave*". If the arrangement is mutually recognised and consensual then a "*submissive*", "*pet*", or "*bottom*" - taken to the extreme, possibly even "*gimp*". If the individual has been emotionally browbeaten into your thrall they may be said to be "*whipped*", with the vulgar "*bitch*" gaining increasing acceptance as a term of endearment.

If the arrangement is not mutually recognised and consensual , or if you are looking for a term like "*boyfriend*" or "*husband*", then eventually "*ex*", "*victim*" or "*plaintiff*" might be appropriate...

Answer (score 9):

He or she is "spoken for".

If a person or thing is spoken for or has been spoken for, someone has claimed them or asked for them, so no-one else can have them.

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/be%20spoken%20for

Answer (score 6):

You can say that you consider him yours *alone* or *exclusively* yours.

Answer (score 5):

Personal and not shared with anyone: Legally, the word is  **SPOUSE**

Comment: Except when it's "girlfriend", "boyfriend", "lover", "significant other", "mistress", etc, you mean?

Comment: well, i would not put mistress or extra marital affair on the same platform.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few options here. The immediate answer could be [boyfriend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boyfriend) or [significant other](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/significant%20other) to refer to someone you're in an exclusive relationship with, though these don't necessarily denote exclusivity. You could also refer to that person as "taken", as in "he's taken".

Answer (score 3):

I think the exact *term* strongly depends on who uses it. From the "owner's" perspective the term can be anything between `beloved one` and `property`, from the opposite standpoint it can be anything between `crazy` and `sadist`. And a third party might describe it as `Something is definitely wrong with this couple` or `These guys are really strange`.

Answer (score 2):

What about "Chattel", it specifically refers to property but when talking about a person that you "own" then it's within context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that it's the *word* (not the *person*) that you consider "personal don't want to share".

So, a [pet name](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pet_name):

> A nickname, especially a name used by those in love with one another.
>
> *My boyfriend won't let me call him by his pet name, Pookie, in public.*

Comment: Although the assumption doesn't fit with the details of the question ("*whom* you consider yours" and "share *him*"), it's still +1 for a good answer to an optimistic skew on the question and it's most likely that the answer the OP is looking for is itself a pet name.

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep "Whom" isn't grammatical (it should be "who", because it's not genitive or dative), therefore the OP is non-English, therefore "whom" and "him" might be supposed to be "which" and "it".

Comment: Confusing "who"/"whom" is common enough even for native speakers - it's the awkward "him" that stands out to me. But I still think that "whom"->"which" and "him"->"it" is an optimistic reach - not at all impossible, but optimistic. They also ask for a term for a person, not a term for a term for a person. They ask "What term is used for a person" not "what do you call the term used for a person".

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep Perhaps a language has masculine and feminine, but not neuter, nouns and pronouns: "English as she is spoke". And I thought that maybe "word-for-a-person" might be some kind of compound noun, similar to "name".

Comment: We are on the same leaf, if not the same page - this was specifically the situation I was imagining when I said "not at all impossible". Still, I think it's a stretch. Even if you make that contraction they are still (literally if not intentionally) asking for a name, not a term for such a name.

Comment: @ChrisW 'Whom' is completely grammatical here; have you forgotten it's also accusative? 'Whom you consider yours' is similar to 'you consider him yours'.

Answer (score 1):

The adj., **Private** is what I would use to refer to such a person.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to capture the fact that this is someone to whom you confide private matters (tell secrets), then that person is a *confidant*.

Answer (score 1):

Typically English speaking countries (America specifically) don't have any nouns related to ownership with no intent to share. The only example I can think of is if we are in a romantic relationship with the individual. Even then, "ownership" is implied rather indirectly. For example: "She is my lady". or "Back off, that is my girlfriend". If it is on a purely friendship level, ownership obviously wouldn't apply but jealousy may occur which is implied in a different manner.